# Show default value when jQuery UISlider loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/m7uhdsy9/)**

I couldn't figure out how to go about doing these following:

1. Show the default item on load. Currently, it loads a blank page and shows the data only when I drag the slider.
2. Show a fading effect when the items are loaded.

Here's the HTML

```
<div class="sli3"></div>
<div class="div-0">
  <div class="div-1"></div>
  <div class="div-2"></div>
  <div class="div-3"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.div-0 {
  position: relative;
}
.div-1 {
  position:absolute;
  top:150px;
  left:150px;
}
.div-2 {
  position:absolute;
  top:100px;
  left:60px;
}
.div-3 {
  position:absolute;
  top:210px;
  left:260px;
}
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $(".sli3").slider({
            animate: true,
        range: "min",
        value: 10,
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            if (ui.value<=20) {
               $(".div-1").text("whatever");
               $(".div-2").html("hello <strong>world</strong>");
               $(".div-3").text("");
            }
            else if (ui.value>=21 && ui.value<50) {
               $(".div-1").text("yay");
               $(".div-2").text("whoo");
               $(".div-3").text("");
            }
            else if (ui.value>=50 && ui.value<70) {
               $(".div-1").text("star");
               $(".div-2").text("wars");
               $(".div-3").text("");
            }
            else if (ui.value>=70 && ui.value<90) {
               $(".div-1").text("night");
               $(".div-2").text("crawler");
               $(".div-3").text("rocks");
            }
            else {
               $(".div-1").text("example text 1");
               $(".div-2").text("example text 2");
               $(".div-3").text("");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of change to your code:

```
$(function() {
    $(".sli3").slider({
        animate: true,
        range: "min",
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        slide: onSlide,
        change: onSlide
    }).slider('value', 10);
});
```

(I took the `slide` function out so I could call it both on change and slide).

Check the update to your demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/m7uhdsy9/1/

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. Any word on fading effect?

Comment: You are welcome :) will appreciate a vote-up on the answer. Regarding the fade-in - in order to do so you need two divs with different content and fadeout/fadein them.